# Why does Q click his fingers?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q

Why does Q click (snap) is fingers whenever he uses his powers? Is there an in-universe reason or is it pure theatrics?

Comment: Because its "snappy"

Comment: Pure theatrics?  Where would you get that idea? I tell ya, you put trial on humanity and makes yourself the judge descending on some bizarre floating throne just once...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't know if there was ever an in-universe given by the writers, producers or anyone else but the finger snap was likely that individual Q's method of focusing their power; although as has been seen on mutliple occassions the motion isn't strictly necessary. If you watch all of the various Q episodes you'll see that each Q has their own action they perform when they use their powers (single finger snap, double finger snap, hand wave, etc).

Comment: In my answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3172/where-does-q-technology-come-from-and-where-did-it-orginate/3177#3177) I postulated that Q-tech responds to mental commands, activated by a physical gesture.  Seems like we think alike.

Comment: When Riker gets Q powers in an episode early in the series, his is a full arm wave. Maybe it's because he's new to his powers or that's just the way it works for him; as was said there was never a reason given.

Comment: @KeithS I got the impression that the full arm wave was kind of overdoing it with an "I'll show you!" expression of emotion.

Answer (score 32):

Not ever defined, that I know of, in universe.. but I'd say it's an intentional self-limiting gesture... with near omnipotence and the ability to simply will things into existence, mere thinking could quickly get messy... unless you created some form of action and tied to the concept of 'invoking' your power, at least in your mind... as Xantec points out, they each have some gesture that they use.  Imagine the chaos for a new Q until they learn to do this!  Every stray thought becoming reality!

This is the same reason the Dresden books have wizards use obscure languages for spells.. once you associate a spell and an effect to a word or phrase, you don't want to trigger it accidentally by thinking it.. so pick something you would not think, except for the specific reason.

I suspect the members of the Q continuum could invoke their powers without their personal gesture... but it might take a pretty strong act of will after a few millennia of habit forming.

Comment: This is the best answer.  The chaos was partially explored in TNG 6x06, "True Q" - Amanda Rogers would accidentally create a bunch of puppies when she turned around, when her pets crossed her mind, and so on.

Comment: Looking back, this was actually made into an issue in the Marvel Comics 'Secret Wars'; Doctor Doom gained the power of the Beyonder, and rails as one of his allies for suggesting a way the Heroes could have survive, as he now must watch his thoughts, let a stray one accidentally cause it to become true.  Which, of course, promptly happens.  A self-limiting gesture like the Q use could have prevented such an issue; it gives him a vulnerability if he can't make the gesture, but saves him from his mere thoughts causing havoc.

Comment: Good thinking. This answer is actually supported in the beginning of "True Q," when Amanda unintentionally brings some puppies into existence.

Answer (score 26):

Because he is a drama queen, and the rest of the Q collective aren't far behind.

Q only appears in human form only when addressing humans.  If Q appears to another race as a member of that race, he does not necessarily have the correct appendages to snap his fingers.  Q knows a making things change with a snap of a finger is an impressive show for humans, and milks it for all he can.

Comment: This is speculation. Q may appear in the John de Lancie form no matter where he goes.

Answer (score 8):

It's questionable that the real Q is actually snapping his fingers (or hand waving, or other kinds of fluorishing) - don't forget, we're only seeing a representation of him in this dimensional/existential/plane/thingie.

But, it kind of makes sense - if you were omnipotent, the last thing you want is for stuff to happen as soon as you think it - it would get kind of chaotic (us mere mortals are rather flighty, and I'd imagine an omnipotent being to be more so). So, link it to a physical gesture to enforce the desire for something to happen.

Comment: This would tie in with the Voyager crew entering the Q continuum. They only got a representation of the place.

Answer (score 4):

Frankly, I think it's just for show. After all, there are certainly occasions in which Q does not snap his fingers, or make any other noticeable movements. At the end of "Encounter at Farpoint," Q leaves without a gesture, and just after commencing the game of Hide and Seek with Amanda Rogers he does the same thing. Amanda also leaves without apparently making any movements ("True Q").

It may be that young Q are taught to do this in order to first definitively establish whatever it is they want to do, so that every stray thought of theirs doesn't immediately become reality. However, for experienced Q, like most of the Q Continuum, it seems that such movements are totally superfluous. Note that in "Q2," Q vanishes after directing a wink toward Captain Janeway. Q most certainly was trying to be showy in that instance!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other excellent answers, I think Q snaps to accentuate the ease at which he uses his powers. The term "it's a snap" refers to something that is very easy to do, like snapping your fingers, so I think this makes sense.