# Is Force lightning from the feet plausible?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

In all the canons of Star Wars, there has not been one instance of a Force-user projecting Force lightning from their feet. Why? Is it implausible?

Comment: Because it would tickle too much?   :-)

Comment: If a [Tricky Trap Tree](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tricky_Trap_Tree) can become a Jedi, very little is implausible.

Comment: smell my feet.. SMELL THEM!

Comment: ...or other *ahem* appendages

Comment: I note that there are no bears in Star Wars either; obviously the bear-repellant has been working there too.

Comment: This assumes [all force user's](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Neti) have *feet*.

Comment: This is a funny question, maybe the funniest Star Wars question I've ever read, but I have to vote to close as not constructive.

Comment: *Is it implausible?"*  I don't know about implausible, but it would sure ruin their loafers.  Are there any sandal wearing Jedi?

Comment: Their are bears in star wars. Just checked wookieepedia.

Comment: Imagine how it would look, if some fearsome sith balanced on one leg while shooting lightning, jedi would be literally rolling on the floor laughing

Comment: Totally implausible. Lightning from the hands? Yup, I buy it. Lightning from the feet? WOAH THERE, that’s just *not believable*.

Comment: Well, you can certainly [channel X-ray energy though your foot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdCfzMacKLM) ... wait, wrong franchise.

Answer (score 6):

In [Star Wars: Legacy #005](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Legacy) we see a Sith Lord projecting Force Lightning from his **entire body**. Although it's cut off by the smoke, I think we can reasonably assume this includes his feet.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure it's plausible, it's just likely to be pretty useless as a fighting skill. For example: [Why does Darth Vader raise his prosthetic arm when channeling the Force?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11289/why-does-darth-vader-raise-his-prosthetic-arm-when-channeling-the-force/53030#53030) suggests that in using the Force, users often use physical gestures to help focus. Hands provide much more control than feet, and in a fight, one nearly always uses the feet to anchor oneself and the fine motor control of the hands and arms to engage in combat. Feet are also typically covered, which might present further problems to the Force user - melty shoe hurtyness.

So I would suggest that while it would be possible to project force lightning from the feet, it would be a very rare (and non-intuitive) thing to do in a real fight.

Comment: It's wouldn't be useless as a fighting skill to [this guy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110363/3823)

Answer (score 1):

## It would be for *[this guy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dug)*

[image]

> Dugs were sentient aliens from the planet of Malastare. Dugs were easily identified by their long snouts and the fact that they walk using their arms

Comment: Is there any reference to a Jedi Dugs? Surely we don't know until we see it.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage, the question is whether it's *plausible*.  I say it is.