# Can Darth Vader use Force Lightning?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, darth-vader

He is only the most potent Force user *ever*.
He is a dark side practitioner.
The Emperor and others use it.

**Why didn't Darth Vader ever use Force Lightning?**

Comment: Because it'd short circuit his armor.

Comment: Are Legends sources acceptable or do you require a canon source?

Comment: @AthenaWidget I've added the star-wars-legends tag, then. In the future, please use this tag to indicate that Legends sources are acceptable.

Comment: I don't have any source of that (and hence no answer), but I read somewhere that high electrical current of force lightning would short-circuit many systems inside his armor, leaving him highly vulnerable or even killing him in process. He was strong with the Force enough to conjure lightning, but he decided not to.

Comment: Related:  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110648/could-an-amputated-emperor-still-shoot-lightning

Comment: The real answer, of course, is that when we first saw Force Lightning in RotJ it was a visual way of conveying to us instantly that Palpatine was not only far from "defenceless" but knew the Force at a whole other level than what we'd seen of Vader.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the Legends continuity, he doesn't because he can't.

According to *Rise of Darth Vader*:

> his arms and legs were mechanical, and he could never cast Force Lightning

According to the *Revenge of the Sith Visual Dictionary*, under *Darth Vader*:

> As a result of having artificial arms, Darth Vader will never be able to conjure Sith lightning-nor be invulnerable to it.

*The Book of Sith* states that

> The second school, or focus, Body, encompasses those abilities that draw from the living Force. They emanate from 
>   your own cells and affect the physical structures of others. For this reason, any cyborg limb or enhancement will hinder your ability to conjur the effects of Body.

It goes on to name Lightning as an example of a "Body" ability.

Comment: How about casting through the body or head?

Comment: See this: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110323/931

Comment: I believe not having limbs isn't a good reason.

Comment: Agreed with @SS-3. Apparently he never actually force chokes via his extended arm if this is the case.

Comment: @ss-3 I didn't make up the reason. I only recorded what was given.

Answer (score 33):

### Disney Canon - No he couldn't.

> *But it was. His promising new apprentice, who was to be the greatest
> Sith who’d ever lived — maimed and burned, perhaps dead. Darth Sidious
> ground his teeth in frustrated anger. Part of him wanted to turn on
> his heel and leave what was left of Darth Vader to burn to ashes in
> the rising lava. **Even if he was alive, even if he could be saved,
> Vader would be crippled.***
>
> ***And not just with his mechanical limbs. The Force — dark side as well
> as light — was generated by living beings, and it took living flesh to
> manipulate it. Darth Vader would never be able to cast blue Force
> lightning; that required living hands, not metal ones.** And with so
> much of his body replaced by machinery, he would never come close to the potential he’d had.*
>
> *It was a great pity, Darth Sidious thought, controlling his anger, but perhaps not irreparable. Even diminished, Darth Vader would still be very strong, and there were no Jedi left to challenge him. Darth Sidious had seen to that himself. So he kept walking until he could bend over the body. And to his surprise, his apprentice was still alive.*
>
> [Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith - Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization))

This is backed up by the new (and fully canon) factbook "[Star Wars in 100 Scenes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_in_100_Scenes)"

> *Vader is skilled with a lightsaber, though **his mechanical arms prevent
> him from creating Force lightning***

Comment: The Junior Novelization is still Legends.

Comment: @RogueJedi - technically it's mixed canon. Since this scene appears in the film and doesn't disagree with the existing continuity, it can be considered Disney Canon **unless contradicted by a higher level source**.

Comment: UGH. I thought Junior Novelizations are fully canon? Which, frankly, makes FAR more sense since they are basically just cloned from the bloody film script unlike real novelizations.

Comment: @DVK - [*All* of the novelisations are canon](http://www.theforce.net/story/literature/Yes_The_Star_Wars_Movie_Novelizations_Are_Canon_157749.asp) so sayeth the Disney Deathstar. Unless contradicted by the film or where they feature scenes that aren't in the films.

Comment: @Richard - I'm tempted to ask about that last one. Are "scenes that aren't in the films" considered non-canon in an explicit statement?

Comment: @DVK - "*where they align with what is seen on screen*" seems pretty definitive to me. I can't see any other way to interpret it.

Comment: @Richard - doesn't to me. I would interpret that as "scenes that are not in film but don't contradict it" are included. That's why I want something explicit covering JUST that scenario, not random generic Disney blather

Comment: @DVK Ugh, these comments epitomize the reason I'm such a fan of the BBC's "no such thing as canon" stance on Doctor Who.

Comment: @KyleStrand - They only say that because Doctor Who is such an awful mess that trying to pin down a real canon basis for the show would be like trying to nail a [Gelth](http://doctorwho.neoseeker.com/wiki/Gelth) to the wall.

Comment: @KyleStrand - I heartily disagree. Having a common set of agreed rules is the most important part of any game, Would chess be any fun if you could make up the rules as you go? Well, yes, for some people that would be enjoyable but for others, damnably frustrating. The same is true of series canon. If people agree what is (and more importantly isn't) part of the agreed worldbuilding, it creates a common framework for people to discuss the show without others bringing in [weird crap](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skippy_the_Jedi_Droid) that only a very small number of people know.

Comment: @Richard Fiction isn't a game except in the Wittgensteinian sense, unless it's explicitly designed as such (e.g. *Heavy Rain*, which admittedly I haven't had a chance to play yet). Did you actually read the article?

Comment: @KyleStrand - Yes. Most telling was the fact that he didn't want the show to have a canon because he personally would find it too hard to get a grip on. What a wuss.

Comment: @Richard I am somewhere between setting my eyebrows askew and giving you a full-on eye-roll. I don't think you've fully grasped the article if your response is "that guy's a wuss, and Doctor Who is a mess."

Comment: @DVK - Extra Disney-canon source added.

Comment: How can Vader use Force Choke, then? I do remember seeing his hand gripping the air and the other guy being choked in the process. If he can use Force Choke with his metal hands, why not Force Lightning?

Comment: @ThalesPereira - I didn't write the thing. The best explanation I can give is that he's merely using his hand as a mental focus. The force isn't actually coming out of his hand.

Answer (score 7):

Somebody mentioned short circuiting the armor suit.

- Biomass amount is independent of force use as in Yoda raises the X-wing. The implication is that any amount of biomass is enough to connect to the force. Loss of a limb should not diminish force connection.
- Vader's force choking is accompanied by the air choke, indicating force use requires a physical action and also that he can safely use the force through that arm.
- Vader killed by force lightning.

We can assume he could have used force lightning, [evidence shows he would have died in the process due to design flaws.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader's_armor) This website mentions a [variant Vader used in a video game](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightning_grenade#cite_note-Star_Wars:_Star_Wars:_Masters_of_Ter.C3.A4s_K.C3.A4si-53).

Comment: You call it "design flaws", Palpatine called it safety switch for case that Vader ever decide to go all Sith over him ;) .

Comment: Do you have a reference for force choke needing the hand gesture? I believe Vader didn't move a finger when he force-choked Admiral Ozzel.

Comment: @Angew You believe wrong. You can do an image search for various things and find screenshots from ANH of Vadar using a hand gesture: "vader force choke" "I find your lack of faith disturbing". Though, when Tarkin asks Vader to release him, you see Vader walking away without the gesture and the Ozzel is still being choked.

Comment: @nanny I actually watched the scene on Youtube before I commented. And I was talking about Admiral Ozzel (choked to death in ESB), not Admiral Motti (choked & released in Tarkin's presence in ANH).

Comment: @Angew Ah, my mistake.

Comment: He can use it in multiplayer in the Revenge of the Sith video game, and he uses it in the story before he's wearing his suit, but this is probably non-canon.

Answer (score 1):

Many people are saying that he couldn't because of his suit, but this is never confirmed in canon. It's like saying that Sidious couldn't use Force choke because he never did it in the movies (he did it in the clone wars).

**There is no definitive canon answer yet** in the movies, the Clone Wars, rebels (tv show), nor the Marvel comics (Vader, Vader down, Star Wars...) or new books. These are the only canon stories until now. They might explain it later though. Just because we haven't seen it, doesn't mean he can't.

Before the Clone Wars Sith magic was never mentioned (in canon) either, and yet Dooku and Sidious used it. The reasoning that X can't use power Y because we haven't seen it is wrong.

Comment: This question is tagged with the star-wars-legends tag, so Legends sources are acceptable -- and the other answers have sources which say that he can't because of his suit.

Comment: Yeah, didn't see the legends tag. I changed the answer a bit because of that. I could delete the answer, but I'll leave it because maybe some people are seeking a canon explanation.

Comment: Okay, better now. Your point is correct, although the fact that Vader never used it in all the many canon works is highly suggestive that he can't use it -- otherwise he would have used it at least once.

Comment: @Null None of the characters went to the bathroom in any of the movies… is this highly suggestive that they can't/don't? Otherwise they would have, at least once.

Comment: @Daniel luckily Robot Chicken cleared that up for us